# Getting a random number in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am little bit new to JS.
I have code which constantly play bets on a certain game, and I am trying to make it skip a random number of sessions from an array I have set.

Right now it skips 4 sessions exactly for some reason. what am I doing wrong?

I would also love to know how can I display the picked number in the console as well.

```
/** -------------- Settings -------------- **/

var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
var roll = array.splice(num, 1);
var yourNumber = roll[ 0 ];

var settings = {

    'baseBet': 1,
    //Your base bet

    'nyanMultiplier': 1.10,
    //What multiplier would you like to grab

    'waitGames': yourNumber,
    //How many games should we wait before starting the bet

};
/** -------------- Settings -------------- **/


var script = {
    'totalWaited': 0,
    'placingBet': false,
    'attempts': 0
};

engine.on('game_starting', function(info)
{

    if(script.totalWaited >= settings.waitGames)
    {
        script.placingBet = true;
        engine.placeBet(Math.round(settings.baseBet) * 100, Math.round(settings.nyanMultiplier * 100), false);
        log('Placing bet now');
    }
    else
    {
        log('Still waiting before we place the bet.');
        script.placingBet = false;
    }

    if(script.placingBet)
    {
        if (engine.lastGamePlay() == 'LOST')
        {
            log('Shot and a miss, maybe next game <3');
        }
        else
        {
            log('YO WE GOT IT. GG <3');
            script.totalWaited = 0;
            script.attempts = 0;
            settings.waitGames;

        }
    }

});

engine.on('game_started', function(data)
{
    if(!script.placingBet)
    {
        script.totalWaited++;
    }
    else
    {
        script.attempts++;
    }
});

function log(message)
{
    console.log('[Bot] ' + message);
}
```

Comment: `Math.floor( Math.random() * 6 )` already gives you an integer between 0 and 5. Why do you still need the array splice/lookup for it? Remember that splice changes the array permanently and that it returns an array of the deleted elements. So if you reuse `var array` multiple times, eventually it'll be empty and roll[0] will be undefined.

Comment: @Shilly Splice changes it permanently. Please update your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array's length is 6, and therefore: `Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);` will create a number between 0-5.

That 'splice' will not only retrieve the amount of cells (1 in your case) from the array, but also mutate the original array and remove those cells.

Unless this is intentional, use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

`yourNumber` can possibly be 4, but your code is right so it should actually be a random number from that array. From here moving to your second request - `console.log(yourNumber)` is how you would print it to the available console (as I can see is already implemented in the `log` function).